# How do I prevent TStrings.SaveToFile creating a final empty line?

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I have a file `.\input.txt` like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

If I read it using [`TStrings.LoadFromFile`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_LoadFromFile@string.html) and write it back (even without applying any changes) using [`TStrings.SaveToFile`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_SaveToFile@string.html), it creates an empty line at the end of the output file.

```
var
  Lines : TStrings;
begin
  Lines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Lines.LoadFromFile('.\input.txt');

    //...

    Lines.SaveToFile('.\output.txt');
  finally
    Lines.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The same behavior can be observed using the [`TStrings.Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) property which will return a string containing an empty line at its end.

Comment: just wondering, why on earth would you want to write it back even when there is no change applied in the file? why not just simply read it?

Comment: @BilalAhmed: sure, it is a simplified test, the same empty line appear when applying changes to the string list

Comment: By "creates an empty line" I guess you mean that your original file does not end with the `\n` character and the function adds the `\n` to the file? Or does the function literally add a `\n` right after an existing `\n` at the end of file? POSIX requires text files to have all their lines terminated by a `\n`, just fyi. Lots of software was written to follow some standards so that's why a lot of editors will add the missing terminating `\n` when you save files by default (e.g. `vim`, IDEs etc all by default make your files POSIX-compliant.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For Delphi 10.1 and newer there is a property `TrailingLineBreak` controlling this behavior.

> When TrailingLineBreak property is True (default value) then Text
>   property will contain line break after last line. When it is False,
>   then Text value will not contain line break after last line. This also
>   may be controlled by soTrailingLineBreak option.

Comment: Great information, I'm working on Delphi2007 and DelphiXE7 but I'll surely be glad to use the `TrailingLineBreak` property as soon as I upgrade the IDE. +1 and accepted

Answer (score 1):

For Delphi 10.1 (Berlin) or newer, the best solution is described in Uwe's answer.

For older Delphi versions, I found a solution by creating a child class of [`TStringList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TStringList) and overriding the [`TStrings.GetTextStr`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_GetTextStr.html) virtual function but I will be glad to know if there is a better solution or if someone else found something wrong in my solution

**Interface:**

```
  uses
    Classes;

  type
    TMyStringList = class(TStringList)
    private
      FIncludeLastLineBreakInText : Boolean;
    protected
      function GetTextStr: string; override;
    public
      constructor Create(AIncludeLastLineBreakInText : Boolean = False); overload;
      property IncludeLastLineBreakInText : Boolean read FIncludeLastLineBreakInText write FIncludeLastLineBreakInText;
    end;
```

**Implementation:**

```
uses
  StrUtils;      

constructor TMyStringList.Create(AIncludeLastLineBreakInText : Boolean = False);
begin
  inherited Create;

  FIncludeLastLineBreakInText := AIncludeLastLineBreakInText;
end;

function TMyStringList.GetTextStr: string;
begin
  Result := inherited;

  if(not IncludeLastLineBreakInText) and EndsStr(LineBreak, Result)
  then SetLength(Result, Length(Result) - Length(LineBreak));
end;
```

**Example:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lines : TStrings;
begin
  Lines := TMyStringList.Create();
  try
    Lines.LoadFromFile('.\input.txt');
    Lines.SaveToFile('.\output.txt');
  finally
    Lines.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that your code occasionally does `SetLength(Result, -2)`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: What do you mean?

Comment: In your `GetTextStr`, if `Length(Result)` is `0`, then you do `SetLength(Result, -2)`, which is bad. It might be the case that the effect is the same as `SetLength(Result, 0)`, but I know of no guarantee regarding that. The official documentation, at least, doesn't contain any such guarantee. (So in theory bad things could happen.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: You're perfectly right, I did not understand. I've fixed the code in the answer, thanks for the explanation

Comment: But now you still got another bug! If `Length(Result) = 1`, then you do `SetLength(Result, -1)`, which is equally bad! In addition, it might be the case that `Result` doesn't end with a line break, in which case you will remove the two last characters from the last line. That's also a bug. (And that might happen, for instance, if you use `TrailingLineBreak`, I suspect. Even if not, there might be other instances.) You really should test if the string really ends with a line break, like `if not IncludeLastLineBreakInText and Result.EndsWith(LineBreak) then`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I took it for granted that in presence of any char, the TStrings would add at least a LineBreak, but this behavior could change in future. Answer updated again, thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, but the new condition is still wrong... :( `Pos(LineBreak, Result) = Length(Result) - Length(LineBreak) + 1`. `Pos` gives the index of the first match. If you string contains 6 line breaks, it will give the position of the first one, but you clearly expect the last one...

Comment: `Result.EndsWith(LineBreak)` works, as does `EndsStr(LineBreak, Result)`, as does `RightStr(Result, 2) = LineBreak`, as does `Copy(Result, Length(Result) - 1, 2) = LineBreak`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: My error again, updated using EndsStr, thanks

Comment: I would ditch the constructor overload and make the property default to true. After all whole purpose of existence of this descendant is that.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Lines.Text:=Trim(Lines.Text);
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?